# CSS module not importing to react component properly

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having an issue with syntax importing a css module stored in the same folder as the react component I'm trying to make. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is not importing properly?

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't work with pictures of code here any more than a mechanic works with pictures of your car.

Comment: Please share CSS module file

Comment: What is the error on your import? Have you tried using the `import * as` syntax as presented in the [gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/css-modules/)?

Comment: [CSS module file](https://i.ibb.co/WKmPD6Q/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with css modules you import an object, and you can pass a given class through accessing this object properties:

```
import styles from "./some-css.module.css"

const Layout = () => (<div className={styles.title}>div styled!</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be `className`. React works in camelCase.

Comment: Yes I fixed this issue, but the CSS file I'm trying to import is still not importing

Comment: What are you exporting/importing from your CSS? Where have you seen that syntax?